# TextView as a button in quiz application not selected on clicking them

Tags: android, kotlin, onclick, buttonclick, android-developer-api

I created a Quiz application in android and used TextView as buttons in Answers option but its not working and i don't know what I have done wrong in my code.

```
override fun onClick(v: View?) {
        when(v?.id) {
            R.id.tvOptionOne -> {
                selectedOptionView(binding.tvOptionOne,1)
            }
            R.id.tvOptionTwo -> {
                selectedOptionView(binding.tvOptionTwo,2)
            }
            R.id.tvOptionThree -> {
                selectedOptionView(binding.tvOptionThree,3)
            }
            R.id.tvOptionFour -> {
                selectedOptionView(binding.tvOptionFour, 4)
            }
            R.id.btnSubmit -> {
                if (mSelectedOptionPosition == 0){
                    mCurrentPossition++

                    when{
                        mCurrentPossition <= mQuestionList!!.size -> {
                            setQuestion()
                        }else ->{
                            Toast.makeText(this, "You have successfully compelted the quiz", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        }
                    }
                }else{
                    val question = mQuestionList?.get(mCurrentPossition -1)
                    if (question!!.correctAnswer != mSelectedOptionPosition){
                        answerView(mSelectedOptionPosition, R.drawable.wrong_option_border_bg)
                    }
                    answerView(question.correctAnswer, R.drawable.correct_option_border_bg)

                    if (mCurrentPossition == mQuestionList!!.size){
                        binding.btnSubmit.text = "FINISH"
                    }else{
                        binding.btnSubmit.text = "GO TO NEXT QUESTION"
                    }
                    mSelectedOptionPosition == 0
                }
            }
        }
    }

 private fun selectedOptionView(tv: TextView, seletedOptionNum:Int){

        defaultOptionsView()
        mSelectedOptionPosition = seletedOptionNum
        tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#363A43"))
        tv.setTypeface(tv.typeface, Typeface.BOLD)
        tv.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.selected_option_border_bg)

    }
```

This code should have resulted in highlight the clicked answer box but it shows nothing after clicking.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXqBb.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this below code to your `onCreate`(for Activity), `onViewCreated`(for Fragment)

```
    tvOptionOne.setOnClickListener(this)
    tvOptionTwo.setOnClickListener(this)
    tvOptionThree.setOnClickListener(this)
    tvOptionFour.setOnClickListener(this)
```

Comment: we using this setOnClickListener(this) with id name for onClick operation for do a click event.

Comment: Thanks! It worked. I was making the silly mistake of using curly braces instead of these braces.

Comment: @ShakibKhatri It's happened. I believe it works. Then mark answer as accepted so that it can be useful for others.